# Easier way to output a triangle of asterisks in Java:

Tags: java

So I finished an assignment and it works, but there has to be a more simple way of doing this; right? The program asks the user to input a number from 1-50 and make an isoceles triangle by printing rows of asterisks according to the number. It also is supposed to give an error if the number is out of range and ask the user if they want to input again. It's finished but just seems long for the intended purpose.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //Declare the variables
    //variable to store input character
    int answer; //variable to identify out and the option to run again


    answer = 0;



    //Main body to show description of program and author
    while(answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This program will diplay an isoceles triangle by printing rows of asterisks according to the number entered", "Program by: Ehlert Donald J",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

      String inputText = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input an integer from one to 50: ");

      int inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(inputText);


      if (inputNumber > 50)
       {     
         //Dialog box to ask the user if they want to run the program again
         answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
            "Would you like to try and enter a valid number?",
            "Wrong",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);         
        }
      else 
       {
            for(int i=1;i<=inputNumber;i++)
           { 
              for(int j=1;j<=inputNumber;j++)
               {
                  if(j<=i)
                  System.out.print("*");
               }
              System.out.println();
           } 
           for(int i=1;i<=inputNumber;i++)
           {
                for(int j=1;j<=inputNumber;j++)
                {
                   if(j>i) 
                System.out.print("*");
                }
           System.out.println();
           }

          answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
            "Would you like to enter another number?",
            "Right",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably should put this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: They're doing this level of assignment but including GUIs? What? As for whether to print, consider mathematically a little bit the number of spaces between two asterisks, and the number of spaces from the left side of an asterisk. You can complete this challenge with a single (top-level) loop.

Comment: well taste differs: I think two loops are cleaner(with no performance impact). But the inner if can be removed and I would count down the second loop, so one can imidiately see what you are doing( = counting down the number of stars) - but this are details.

Comment: I forgot: if performance matters you could work with String/StringBuilder/StringBuffer and reduce the print calls(and remove the inner loops completely).

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what the output is supposed to look like, but here is a pretty easy way to print 'solid' triangles...

```
public void printTriangle(int size)
{
    char[] line = new char[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) line[i] = ' ';

    int height = size/2;
    int middle = size/2;

    for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        line[middle + i] = '*';
        line[middle - i] = '*';
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    line[0] = '*';
    line[size-1] = '*';
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

If you want a border printed instead of a solid triangle, you can just use:

```
line[middle + i] = '*';
line[middle - i] = '*';
System.out.println(line);
line[middle + i] = ' ';
line[middle - i] = ' ';
```

This does not handle even numbers properly, but you didn't mention what to do about that!